# Android studio1.1.0で、推奨されるjdkは?

Tags: java, android-studio

windows7環境で、最新のjdkを使え、と言うのは、jdk8が使えない事から自明ですが、jdk7のバージョンは、どれを使うのが適切なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

インストール時点で一番新しいものを使ってください。

Comment: さま

有難うございます。
現時点では、正常動作してませんが、
再度Tryしてみます。